# Documentation regarding using traits for associated types

Tags: rust

I'm unclear as to why `traits` are usable within the RHS of the `type` syntax for what I recognize as an associated type. I searched through the [language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html) and could not find it, but am not sure if I did not find it due to lack of familiarity/understanding, or because it's as of yet undocumented.

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=49e356024c8b113722513aa78fad24e5) with the same code.

```
trait ATrait {
    fn a(&self) -> f64;
}

trait BTrait {
    fn b(&self) -> f64;
}

trait Container {
    // Why can we just use 'traits'?
    type Item: ATrait + BTrait;
    fn describe_container() -> i32;
}

struct ContainerType;
impl Container for ContainerType {
    type Item = ItemType;
    fn describe_container() -> i32 {
        42
    }
}

struct ItemType;
impl ATrait for ItemType {
    fn a(&self) -> f64 {
        3.141
    }
}

impl BTrait for ItemType {
    fn b(&self) -> f64 {
        2.718
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ct = ContainerType {};
    ContainerType::describe_container();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears in the reference [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html). Specifically, *AssociatedItem* refers to [*TypeAlias*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html), and it includes ( `:` [*TypeParamBounds*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html) )<sup>?</sup> and mentions (at the end of the page) that:

> A type alias with [*TypeParamBounds*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html) may only specified when used as an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-types) in a [trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html).

These bounds mean that for every type that implement the trait, the type provided for this associated type will have to implement the mentioned traits. In your example, `ItemType`, specified as `Container::Item` for `ContainerType`, must implement `ATrait` and `BTrait`, or [errors will be emitted](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e15a2e28564be16c46665f8b399fa71f):

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ItemType: BTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:17
   |
17 |     type Item = ItemType;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `BTrait` is not implemented for `ItemType`
   |
note: required by a bound in `Container::Item`
  --> src/main.rs:11:25
   |
11 |     type Item: ATrait + BTrait;
   |                         ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Container::Item`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ItemType: ATrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:17
   |
17 |     type Item = ItemType;
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `ATrait` is not implemented for `ItemType`
   |
note: required by a bound in `Container::Item`
  --> src/main.rs:11:16
   |
11 |     type Item: ATrait + BTrait;
   |                ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Container::Item`
```